# "Investment" or "Capital investment"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, verbs

I am going to enter into a partnership with an American company and want to know how much capital they have and what would be the assets and capabilities they intend to bring into the market in my question. How should I ask them idiomatically about the amount they would tend to provide us as a partner in our project?

> - How much can you invest in this project?
> - How much **capital** can you invest in this project?

I think, while the verb "invest" encapsulates the "capital" in it, using capital would be optional here, (although using that collocation can make my sentence sound more scientific and financial. 
Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: That sounds like a question for an attorney who specializes in international investments, not for ELL.

Comment: @Jack O'Flaherty just please tell me if my sentence without "capital" sounds idiomatic or it is usually said along with that word? I would be really appreciative.

Comment: Either sentence is equally idiomatic. If you use the word "capital", you are probably referring to money. The bare word "invest" might as easily refer to money, time or effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to ask: "How much capital can you invest in this project?"

Capital refers to where the money is coming from. In other words, what is the source of the funds? An investment refers to the money the company is willing to promise you.

"How much can you invest in this project?" is a much broader question and can leave you with much less information than you would like.

"How much capital can you invest in this project?" will cover more bases and give you the required financial information to deem if the they are worth pursuing as a partner.

For even more clarity, I would recommend posing two separate questions: What is your capital? How much are you willing to invest? <---- This would be less ambiguous and would more thoroughly answer your question as well as prompt the necessary financial discussions.